# Long array in swift file

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode

Shorted the title to make it easier for people to understand the problem.

When I've finished adding data to an array, I need to open Activity Monitor and close two processes (Swift and SourceKitService).
Because of the array, Swift and SourceKitService use all available RAM and they have to be closed.
How can I keep adding to the array in the swift file without having to continually close processes?

Comment: Confused about this- Closed. This question is off-topic. It is not currently accepting answers.
Edit the question to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem. This will help others answer the question.
Closed 2 hours ago by El Tomato, Gereon, matt.
(Private feedback for you)

Comment: Desired behaviour is in the title, seems like a specific problem too I would have thought

Answer (score 1):

The Swift compiler is probably getting tied up in knots because your array is long AND it can’t determine the type so needs to rely on implicit checking which is expensive.

The longer the array the bigger the problem.

You may need  to provide an explicit type to your declaration.

E.g

```
let foo: [String] = [“boa”,”fool”,”zoo”,...
```

Vs

```
let foo = [“boa”,”fool”,”zoo”,...
```

Whatever the type of the array elements you should declare this explicitly to assist the compiler when you encounter this issue.

Yes, it should just work, but this is real life and the Swift compiler is young.